# Modify the DataGridCell background color when a style is already set?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not much of a UI guy but I have been task with what seemed to be a simple thing to do.

I need to change a few of the column backgrounds of an already established working datagrid for what the users say will be easier to read. Everything I read points to using `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">`. This would make sense and easily doable except there is a sty;e already applied to a different target and I can't add another.

How can I modify the DataGridCell background color when a style is already set?

This is what one of the columns looks like now

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colGoalPercentCases" u:XAMLProperties.GroupName="Cases" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=GoalPercent_Cases, TargetNullValue='', Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#,#.00\\%;-#,#.00\\%}',NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="GoalLostFocus" />
            <EventSetter Event="LostKeyboardFocus" Handler="GoalLostKeyboardFocus" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=colGoalPercentCases}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="CS %" Margin="1,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbCasePercent" Margin="1,0,10,0" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**EDIT:** Added code for Cell Style - Resolved my issue

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC7D9FF"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily change cell style for certain columns via `CellStyle` property. use `BasedOn` property of a Style to inherit existing style:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chocolate"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Ah yes, <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle> was the key element that needed to be added. thank you so much